# How to always show full email address of sender and recipients in Apple mail

Tags: mail.app, email

According to [this os/2 daily article](https://osxdaily.com/2015/12/17/show-full-name-email-address-mac-mail-os-x/?unapproved=9001890&moderation-hash=ab82bcd4e7275de82a2b1be178b24495#comment-9001890) we should be able to see the full email addresses by unchecking `smart addresses`:

> Uncheck the box for “Use Smart Addresses” – under this you’ll see a note about “Turn this off to always display names and addresses.” which is exactly what we’re looking to do

I have done so:

[image]

Yet the email addresses are all the short names without the full email addresses.  So how can this be done?  I am on Catalina and converting to Big Sur soon.

Comment: I use Monterey so I don't know whether it applies to Catalina as well, but after recent update I also lost full email addresses. Ticking 'Use Smart Addresses', opening one mail, closing it, and then unticking did trick for me - now name and e-mail address are again displayed as they should.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg That [hack] works!  Please make that an answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is hack that seems to work in Monterey and Catalina:

- switch on 'Use Smart Addresses' by ticking appropriate box
- open one e-mail and close it
- switch off 'Use Smart Addresses' by unticking

Now you should see both name and e-mail address.

PS - I don't know whether it is needed to open one mail or not. I did it this way. There is probability that it's suffice just to switch-on, switch-off but I have no way to verify it as my problem went away (and hopefully there will be no 'next time' to try it :-))

Comment: Very strange bug but solution works great!